# Convert all first letter to upper case, rest lower for each word

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a string of text (about 5-6 words mostly) that I need to convert.

Currently the text looks like:

```
THIS IS MY TEXT RIGHT NOW
```

I want to convert it to:

```
This Is My Text Right Now
```

I can loop through my collection of strings, but I am not sure how to go about performing this text modification.

Comment: Related (not duplicate): *[Make first letter of a string upper case (with maximum performance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135317)*

Answer (score 259, accepted):

```
string s = "THIS IS MY TEXT RIGHT NOW";

s = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(s.ToLower());
```

Comment: Note that while this method will do what the questioner has asked, it's a naive algorithm that just capitalizes each word, without regard to what kind of word it is.  It's not really "title case" since rules for title casing differ in different languages.  It's not even correct for English.  For instance, the title "about a boy" should be "About a Boy" in English, but this method would give "About A Boy".  If you want *true* title case, you'll have to write your own method.

Comment: I wouldn't call them jerks. The thing with "ToTitleCase" is that it's culture-dependent, hence it has to be in the System.Globalization namespace. Going through CurrentThread is just done to get the current Culture of the Thread (Be aware that this may cause different behavior if the user has a different Locale!). You could as well do "CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase()", which may be better as InvariantCulture behaves the same on all cultures. Out of interest George: Where would you put a Culture-Specific String function?

Comment: Also note the comments about ALL UPPERCASE strings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx

Answer (score 88):

I probably prefer to invoke the **ToTitleCase** from **CultureInfo** (*System.Globalization*) than **Thread.CurrentThread** (*System.Threading*):

```
string s = "THIS IS MY TEXT RIGHT NOW";
s = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(s.ToLower());
```

But it should be the same as [jspcal's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943273/convert-all-first-letter-to-upper-case-rest-lower-for-each-word/1943293#1943293).

**EDIT**

Actually, those solutions are **not the same**: `CurrentThread` --calls--> `CultureInfo`!

---

**System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture**

```
string s = "THIS IS MY TEXT RIGHT NOW";
s = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(s.ToLower());

IL_0000:  ldstr       "THIS IS MY TEXT RIGHT NOW"
IL_0005:  stloc.0     // s
IL_0006:  call        System.Threading.Thread.get_CurrentThread
IL_000B:  callvirt    System.Threading.Thread.get_CurrentCulture
IL_0010:  callvirt    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.get_TextInfo
IL_0015:  ldloc.0     // s
IL_0016:  callvirt    System.String.ToLower
IL_001B:  callvirt    System.Globalization.TextInfo.ToTitleCase
IL_0020:  stloc.0     // s
```

---

**System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture**

```
string s = "THIS IS MY TEXT RIGHT NOW";
s = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(s.ToLower());

IL_0000:  ldstr       "THIS IS MY TEXT RIGHT NOW"
IL_0005:  stloc.0     // s
IL_0006:  call        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.get_CurrentCulture
IL_000B:  callvirt    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.get_TextInfo
IL_0010:  ldloc.0     // s
IL_0011:  callvirt    System.String.ToLower
IL_0016:  callvirt    System.Globalization.TextInfo.ToTitleCase
IL_001B:  stloc.0     // s
```

---

References:

- *[CultureInfo Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo)*
- *[Thread.CurrentCulture Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.currentculture#System_Threading_Thread_CurrentCulture)*

Answer (score 18):

There are a couple of ways to go about converting the first character of a string to upper case.

The first way is to create a method that simply caps the first character and appends the rest of the string using a substring:

```
public string UppercaseFirst(string s)
{
    return char.ToUpper(s[0]) + s.Substring(1);
}
```

The second way (which is slightly faster) is to split the string into a character array and then rebuild the string:

```
public string UppercaseFirst(string s)
{
    char[] a = s.ToCharArray();
    a[0] = char.ToUpper(a[0]);
    return new string(a);
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't exactly answer the question adequately. The title of the question is "Convert all first letter to upper case, rest lower for each word". However, this solution only capitalizes the first letter of the entire string. Therefore, this solution would convert "hello world" to "Hello world", rather than "Hello World".

Comment: That's a good point. This solution could be completed if you used something like string[] words = s.Split(' '); and then call the above methods inside a foreach (word in words) loop, reconstructing the string...

The other solutions seem more elegant.

Answer (score 10):

Untested but something like this should work:

```
var phrase = "THIS IS MY TEXT RIGHT NOW";
var rx = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(?<=\w)\w");
var newString = rx.Replace(phrase,new MatchEvaluator(m=>m.Value.ToLowerInvariant()));
```

Essentially it says "preform a regex match on all occurrences of an alphanumeric character that follows another alphanumeric character and then replace it with a lowercase version of itself"

Comment: This one also makes all uppercase words start with uppercase and continue with lowercase. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Have you had time to [test it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1943339/edit)?

Answer (score 10):

If you're using on a web page, you can also use CSS:

`style="text-transform:capitalize;"`

Comment: Why CSS? 
When the question is asking for **c# asp.net regex**

Comment: The tag `ASP.NET` shows the OP is doing it on WEB. Of course this is not the answer of question because OP required the solution in `C#` but it solves the problem and can be an alternative solution. +1

Answer (score 7):

When building big tables, speed is a concern so [Jamie Dixon's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943273/convert-all-first-letter-to-upper-case-rest-lower-for-each-word/1943298#1943298) second function is best, but it doesn't completely work as is...

It fails to take all of the letters to lowercase, and it only capitalizes the first letter of the string, not the first letter of each word in the string... the below option fixes both issues:

```
    public string UppercaseFirstEach(string s)
    {
        char[] a = s.ToLower().ToCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < a.Count(); i++ )
        {
            a[i] = i == 0 || a[i-1] == ' ' ? char.ToUpper(a[i]) : a[i];

        }

        return new string(a);
    }
```

Although at this point, whether this is still the fastest option is uncertain. The `Regex` solution provided [by George Mauer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943273/convert-all-first-letter-to-upper-case-rest-lower-for-each-word/1943339#1943339) might be faster... someone who cares enough should test it.

Comment: it works, but i changed this "a.Count()" to a.Length

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if the solution below is more or less efficient than [jspcal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943273/convert-all-first-letter-to-upper-case-rest-lower-for-each-word/1943293#1943293), but I'm pretty sure it requires less object creation than [Jamie's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943273/convert-all-first-letter-to-upper-case-rest-lower-for-each-word/1943298#1943298) and [George's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943273/convert-all-first-letter-to-upper-case-rest-lower-for-each-word/1943339#1943339).

```
string s = "THIS IS MY TEXT RIGHT NOW";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.Length);
bool capitalize = true;
foreach (char c in s) {
    sb.Append(capitalize ? Char.ToUpper(c) : Char.ToLower(c));
    capitalize = !Char.IsLetter(c);
}
return sb.ToString();
```

Comment: If we're concerned with object creation, why not do it in-place with a for loop indexing over s instead of using a StringBuilder?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the first answer, remember to change string selectionstart index to the end of the word or you will get the reverse order of letters in the string.

```
s.SelectionStart = s.Length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this technique; It returns the desired result

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(str.ToLower());
```

And don't forget to use **`System.Globalization`**.

Comment: What do you mean by "use System.Globalization"? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @PeterMortensen As far as I remember, I think you just type `using System.Globalization;` at the start of your C# file.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the possible solutions you might be interested in. Traversing an array of characters from right to left and vice versa in one loop.

```
public static string WordsToCapitalLetter(string value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("value");
    }

    int inputValueCharLength = value.Length;
    var valueAsCharArray = value.ToCharArray();

    int min = 0;
    int max = inputValueCharLength - 1;

    while (max > min)
    {
        char left = value[min];
        char previousLeft = (min == 0) ? left : value[min - 1];

        char right = value[max];
        char nextRight = (max == inputValueCharLength - 1) ? right : value[max - 1];

        if (char.IsLetter(left) && !char.IsUpper(left) && char.IsWhiteSpace(previousLeft))
        {
            valueAsCharArray[min] = char.ToUpper(left);
        }

        if (char.IsLetter(right) && !char.IsUpper(right) && char.IsWhiteSpace(nextRight))
        {
            valueAsCharArray[max] = char.ToUpper(right);
        }

        min++;
        max--;
    }

    return new string(valueAsCharArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[jspcal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943273/convert-all-first-letter-to-upper-case-rest-lower-for-each-word/1943293#1943293) as a string extension.

#### File *Program.cs*

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myText = "MYTEXT";
        Console.WriteLine(myText.ToTitleCase()); //Mytext
    }
}
```

#### File *StringExtensions.cs*

```
using System;
public static class StringExtensions
{

    public static string ToTitleCase(this string str)
    {
        if (str == null)
            return null;

        return System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(str.ToLower());
    }
}
```