# Format a String literal

Tags: c#, .net, string

I want to format a string value by a certain format that the `first letter` of it be in `Uppercase`.
e.g:

```
string.Format("{0}", "myName"); //Output must be : "MyName"
```

How can I do it?

Comment: And if `myname` is `"fred jones"`, is that `"Fred jones"`, or `"Fred Jones"` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135317/make-first-letter-of-each-word-upper-case

Comment: I want the `"Fred jones"`. But what about `"Fred Jones"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check MSDN for your case, see [TextInfo.ToTitleCase Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx) .

```
string myString = "wAr aNd pEaCe";        
TextInfo myTI = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
Console.WriteLine("\"{0}\" to titlecase: {1}", myString, myTI.ToTitleCase(myString));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to capitalise the first letter, maybe:

```
string s = string.Format("{0}", char.ToUpper(myname[0]) + myname.Substring(1));
```

Otherwise, to capitalise each word maybe use `TextInfo.ToTitleCase` ?

```
string s = string.Format("{0}",
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(myname));
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
string test = "myname";
string formatted = System.Globalization.CultureInfo
                         .CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(test);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo   = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;

Console.WriteLine("{0}", textInfo.ToTitleCase(myname));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = "myname";
var charArray = input.ToArray();
charArray[0] = char.ToUpper(charArray[0]);

string result = new string(charArray);
```