# I need first letter upper and rest lower to my if in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, uppercase, lowercase

first of all I want to sorry for my English...
I have an if:

```
if (imię.Text.Length > 2 && char.IsUpper(imię.Text,0) && char.IsLower(imię.Text,1)==true)
{
     PanelImie.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Check_icon;
     imietest = true;
}
else
{
     PanelImie.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Sign_Error_icon;
     imietest = false;
}
blokowanieOK();
```

And a form like on the picture:

In field "imię"(name) and "nazwisko"(surname) I set the first letter must be upper that's ok but I want the rest off letters be lower and checkicon will be true in this situation. At the moment I can write Uppercase ewerywhere and my program show me that's ok... How to change this if to First letter must be upper and rest of letters must be lower and then checkicon will be ok?

Comment: So are you saying when you write it (`imie`) all in uppercase the `if` condition is still satisfied?

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135317/make-first-letter-of-a-string-upper-case

Comment: I don't think he's "making" a string anything in this scenario. He's testing if it is/isn't. I believe, but he hasn't clarified yet

Comment: This is a terrible duplicate flag in my opinion. It's nothing like the other question.

Comment: You probably want change your test to `imię.Text.Length >= 2`, as it will always fail on short surnames like *Yi*, *Ho*, and *Wu*.

Comment: This is not a duplicate since this one explicitly wants the remaining chars as lowercase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a bit of LINQ in your `if` statement

```
if (imię.Text.Length > 2 && char.IsUpper(imię.Text[0]) && imie.Text.Skip(1).All(char.IsLower))
```

Comment: Why would he check if the first character `IsUpper` then test if all (including the first) `IsLower`? This condition will never be met.

Comment: whoops forgot to add the Skip

Comment: Jonsey thank you for your's so fast answer! Thank you very much it works! :) I don't know Linq before. One more time big thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 if ( imię.Text.ToString().Length > 2 && imię.Text == imię.Text.ToString().ToTitleCase())
   {

   }
```

Although, if the length check ( imię.Text.Length > 2) is only included in your question to prevent errors from (char.IsLower( imię.Text, 1 )) it's not necessary for the if statement.

Comment: Best answer. +1. Although I'd change the variable name and body to make it more relevant.

Comment: Just noticed you're not doing the length check either.

Comment: I assumed the OP only used the length check to prevent errors on the second char check. I added it back in and added a caveat that it's not necessary for checking the case.

Comment: Yeah I think he's just using it to prevent the exception

Comment: Be careful, `"NAZWISKO".ToTitleCase() == "NAZWISKO"` is `true` in all (?) cultures (and `Text` doesn't have a `ToTitleCase()` method - you're looking for `TextInfo` :)).