# How to split first two characters and followed by next two characters after the period of a email address (test.mail@test.com=tema)

Tags: c#, regex

I have a email id like below

```
string email=test.mail@test.com;
string myText = email.split(".");
```

i am not sure who split first two characters and followed by two  characters after the period or dot.

```
myText = tema //(desired output)
```

Comment: he wants **te**st. **ma**il@test.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use LINQ  ;)

```
string myText = string.Join("", email.Remove(email.IndexOf('@')).Split('.')
                                .Select(r =>new String(r.Take(2).ToArray())));
```

- First Remove text after `@`, *(including `@`)*
- Then split on `.`
- From the returned array take first two characters from each element and convert it to array
- Pass the array of characters to `String` constructor creating a string
- using `String.Join` to combine returned strings element.

Comment: ,is it possible, can i get the first letter as Captial in the return string value?

Comment: myText = Tema // I want the result is like this where the return string's first character is a captial letter

Comment: @Selva, that is a separate issue and it already has too many answers here on stackoverflow. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135317/make-first-letter-of-a-string-upper-case-for-maximum-performance

Answer (score 2):

Another Linq solution:

```
string first = new string(email.Take(2).ToArray());
string second = new string(email.SkipWhile(c => c != '.').Skip(1).Take(2).ToArray());
string res = first + second;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string.Join(string.Empty, email.Substring(0, email.IndexOf("@")).Split('.').Select(x => x.Substring(0, 2)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Lots of creative answers here, but the most important point is that `Split()` is the wrong tool for this job.  It's much easier to use `Replace()`:

```
myText = Regex.Replace(email, @"^(\w{2})[^.]*\.(\w{2})[^.]*@.+$", "$1$2");
```

Note that I'm making a lot of simplifying assumptions here.  Most importantly, I'm assuming the original string contains the email address and nothing else (you're not searching for it), that the string is well formed (you're not trying to validate it), and that both of substrings you're interested in start with at least two word characters.

Comment: Hi Alan, Thanks for your regex. But it is not getting compiled. I am getting error like Cannot resolve  method Replace(string,string,string,string). Could you please check?

Comment: Are you `using System.Text.RegularExpressions`?

Comment: D'oh!  I don't know how I did it, but I repeated the third argument.  It's fixed now.

Comment: can you please provide the updated regular expression?

Comment: I don't get you.  I had accidentally repeated the third argument `, "$1$2"`, so I removed the second one.  I didn't change the regex.