# Converting Sql Query to LinQ with Reverse SQL Command

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, reverse

I have a query where it reverse the characters and capitalize the first letter after the reversed. In my T-SQL, it's working but when I'm trying to convert it to Linq query, I'm having a issues that says

```
Reverse is not supported
```

Here's my working query

```
Upper(Left(REVERSE(Firstname),1))+Lower(Reverse(Left(Right(Firstname, LEN(Firstname)),LEN(Firstname)-1))) as NameReverse

// "Name" is the result without reverse, but after the reverse query, it will be
// "Eman"
```

Here's my reverse in linq that doesn't work

```
TheLengthOfName = name.FirstName.Reverse()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [This might help.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string) Also, your sql is over-complicated. This works the same: `UPPER(LEFT(REVERSE(FirstName), 1)) + LOWER(RIGHT(REVERSE(FirstName), LEN(Firstname) - 1))`

Comment: Hi @ZoharPeled, how can I achieve it on LinQ? :)

Comment: You could use one of the solutions offered in that post to create an extension method for string reverse.

Comment: Oh, do you have a sample code? Thank you

Comment: Sample code of what? creating extension methods?

Comment: No, sample code to convert UPPER(LEFT(REVERSE(FirstName), 1)) + LOWER(RIGHT(REVERSE(FirstName), LEN(Firstname) - 1)) to linq.

Comment: You don't need linq for that, you simply need to create 2 extension methods for strings - one for reverse and one for [capitalizing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135317/make-first-letter-of-a-string-upper-case-with-maximum-performance). After you have these methods all the rest is just as normal.

Comment: But my list of names are derive from table with a column of Firstname. That's why i need to return a linq query of ReverseName column.

Comment: `var x = name.FirstName.Reverse().Capitalize()`

Comment: @ZoharPeled I am looking for C# expression not C# statement :(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [R. Martinho Fernandes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46642/r-martinho-fernandes) that provided [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15111719/3094533) And to [RobinHood70](https://stackoverflow.com/users/502255/robinhood70) that offered an improvement, I created an extension method for string reverse:

```
public static string Reverse(this string s)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    {
        return s;
    }
    var info = new StringInfo(s);
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = info.LengthInTextElements - 1; i > -1 ; i--)
    {
        sb.Append(info.SubstringByTextElements(i, 1));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

I've slighly modified [Darren Sherwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/329367/darren)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135317/make-first-letter-of-a-string-upper-case-with-maximum-performance/27073919#27073919), to return the capitalized string you wanted:

```
public static string Capitalize(this string s)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
    {
        return s;
    }
    var charArray = s.ToLower().ToCharArray();
    charArray[0] = Char.ToUpper(charArray[0]);
    return new string(charArray);
}
```

Now, to combine it with a linq query you need something like this:

```
var query = from person in people
            select person.FirstName.Reverse().Capitalize();
```

[See a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/EFIU42719)

Comment: But I'm looking for C# expression not C# statement :(