# How to auto capitalize the first letter of every word in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm having a hard time in finding a code for auto capitalizes letter for every word. Hope you can help me!

Comment: If you cannot find it, write it! If you then run into trouble we are here to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make first letter of a string upper case (with maximum performance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135317/make-first-letter-of-a-string-upper-case-with-maximum-performance)

Answer (score 1):

use culture info class :

```
String test = "HELLO THERE";
string s = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(test.ToLower());
// Hello There
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about

> [TextInfo.ToTitleCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> Generally, title casing converts the first character of a word to uppercase and the rest of the characters to lowercase. However, this method does not currently provide proper casing to convert a word that is entirely uppercase, such as an acronym. The following table shows the way the method renders several strings.