# Unsafe Create string directly from Array

Tags: c#, unsafe

The current quickest way I know to uppercase the first letter of a string is as follows:

```cs
var array = str.ToCharArray();
array[0] = char.ToUpper(array[0]);
return new string(array);
```

This involves 2 array allocations: `char.ToUpper(array[0])` and the copy to strings internal buffer in `new string(array)`.

Since I know that `array` doesn't escape this method is there an way using unsafe code to avoid the second allocation?

Comment: Maybe this helps you: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/creating-strings-with-no-allocation-overhead-using-string-create-csharp

Comment: @SomeBody definitely looks like a start. Will try and post full solution as answer soon

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135317/make-first-letter-of-a-string-upper-case-with-maximum-performance

Comment: Thanks @Genusatplay, but none of that suggests a way to avoid this extra allocation

Comment: You check only first answers?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63886117/5446495

Comment: nice, but that's more than 15 answers down!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you asked for the "***quickest***" way, let's benchmark a couple of things. We as programmers like to work with empirical evidence after all **nods convincingly**

**OldSchool**

```
public string OldSchool(string value) 
   => char.ToUpper(value[0]) + value[1..];
```

**Span**

```
public string TestSpan(string value)
   => string.Create(value.Length, value, (span, str) =>
   {
      str.AsSpan().CopyTo(span);
      span[0] = char.ToUpper(span[0]);
   });
```

**Unsafe**

```
public unsafe string TestUnsafe(string value)
{
   var result = new string(value);
   fixed (char* p = result) p[0] = char.ToUpper(p[0]);
   return result;
}
```

**Unsafe Ascii only**

```
public unsafe string TestUnsafeAscii(string value)
{
   var result = new string(value);
   fixed (char* p = result) 
      if(p[0] >= 'a' && p[0] <= 'z') *p += (char)32;
   return result;
}
```

**SuperUnsafe**

<sub>***Note** : this is for the super brave, where the strings are not inturned and where mutation is not a problem*</sub>

```
public unsafe string SuperUnsafe(string value)
{
   fixed (char* p = value) p[0] = char.ToUpper(p[0]);
   return value;
}
```

## Benchmarks

**Configuration**

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.12.1, OS=Windows 10.0.19041.804 (2004/?/20H1)
AMD Ryzen 9 3900X, 1 CPU, 24 logical and 12 physical cores
.NET Core SDK=5.0.201
  [Host]        : .NET Core 5.0.4 (CoreCLR 5.0.421.11614, CoreFX 5.0.421.11614), X64 RyuJIT
  .NET Core 5.0 : .NET Core 5.0.4 (CoreCLR 5.0.421.11614, CoreFX 5.0.421.11614), X64 RyuJIT

Job=.NET Core 5.0  Runtime=.NET Core 5.0
```

**Results**

| Method | N | Mean | Error | StdDev | Ratio | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OldSchool | 5 | 44.89 ns | 0.389 ns | 0.364 ns | 1.00 | 0.0105 | - | - | 88 B |
| Span | 5 | 26.37 ns | 0.170 ns | 0.159 ns | 1.00 | 0.0038 | - | - | 32 B |
| Unsafe | 5 | 25.15 ns | 0.128 ns | 0.119 ns | 1.00 | 0.0038 | - | - | 32 B |
| UnsafeAscii | 5 | 11.92 ns | 0.093 ns | 0.073 ns | 1.00 | 0.0038 | - | - | 32 B |
| SuperUnsafe | 5 | 10.22 ns | 0.051 ns | 0.045 ns | 1.00 | - | - | - | - |

| Method | N | Mean | Error | StdDev | Ratio | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OldSchool | 10 | 49.31 ns | 0.595 ns | 0.527 ns | 1.00 | 0.0134 | - | - | 112 B |
| Span | 10 | 27.71 ns | 0.548 ns | 0.512 ns | 1.00 | 0.0057 | - | - | 48 B |
| Unsafe | 10 | 26.76 ns | 0.142 ns | 0.126 ns | 1.00 | 0.0057 | - | - | 48 B |
| UnsafeAscii | 10 | 13.40 ns | 0.103 ns | 0.096 ns | 1.00 | 0.0057 | - | - | 48 B |
| SuperUnsafe | 10 | 10.28 ns | 0.106 ns | 0.094 ns | 1.00 | - | - | - | - |

| Method | N | Mean | Error | StdDev | Ratio | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OldSchool | 100 | 83.52 ns | 0.966 ns | 0.903 ns | 1.00 | 0.0564 | - | - | 472 B |
| Span | 100 | 45.77 ns | 0.441 ns | 0.412 ns | 1.00 | 0.0268 | - | - | 224 B |
| Unsafe | 100 | 44.07 ns | 0.511 ns | 0.453 ns | 1.00 | 0.0268 | - | - | 224 B |
| UnsafeAscii | 100 | 31.45 ns | 0.382 ns | 0.357 ns | 1.00 | 0.0268 | - | - | 224 B |
| SuperUnsafe | 100 | 10.26 ns | 0.078 ns | 0.073 ns | 1.00 | - | - | - | - |

| Method | N | Mean | Error | StdDev | Ratio | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OldSchool | 1000 | 512.05 ns | 2.909 ns | 2.578 ns | 1.00 | 0.4864 | 0.0052 | - | 4072 B |
| Span | 1000 | 260.35 ns | 2.593 ns | 2.425 ns | 1.00 | 0.2418 | 0.0017 | - | 2024 B |
| Unsafe | 1000 | 255.06 ns | 1.587 ns | 1.407 ns | 1.00 | 0.2418 | 0.0017 | - | 2024 B |
| UnsafeAscii | 1000 | 247.60 ns | 2.500 ns | 2.338 ns | 1.00 | 0.2418 | 0.0017 | - | 2024 B |
| SuperUnsafe | 1000 | 10.21 ns | 0.060 ns | 0.056 ns | 1.00 | - | - | - | - |

**Full Test Code**

```
public class Test
{

   private string _data;

   private static readonly Random random = new Random(42);

   public static string RandomString(int length)
   {
      const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
      return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
         .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
   }

   [Params(5, 10, 100, 1000)] public int N;

   [GlobalSetup]
   public void Setup()
   {
      _data = RandomString(N);
   }

   [Benchmark]
   public string OldSchool() => OldSchool(_data);

   public string OldSchool(string value)
      => char.ToUpper(value[0]) + value[1..];

   [Benchmark]
   public string Span() => TestSpan(_data);

   public string TestSpan(string value)
      => string.Create(value.Length, value, (span, str) =>
      {
         str.AsSpan().CopyTo(span);
         span[0] = char.ToUpper(span[0]);
      });

   [Benchmark]
   public string Unsafe() => TestUnsafe(_data);

   public unsafe string TestUnsafe(string value)
   {
      var result = new string(value);
      fixed (char* p = result) p[0] = char.ToUpper(p[0]);
      return result;
   }

   [Benchmark]
   public unsafe string SuperUnsafe() => SuperUnsafe(_data);

   public unsafe string SuperUnsafe(string value)
   {
      fixed (char* p = value) p[0] = char.ToUpper(p[0]);
      return value;
   }

   [Benchmark]
   public string UnsafeAscii() => TestUnsafeAscii(_data);

   public unsafe string TestUnsafeAscii(string value)
   {
      var result = new string(value);
      fixed (char* p = result) 
         if(p[0] >= 'a' && p[0] <= 'z') *p += (char)32;
      return result;
   }
}
```

Comment: Note that the Unsafe version could end up being super unsafe if https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/31971 is ever implemented

Comment: @YairHalberstadt yeah interesting, this would be a breaking change if they turned it on by default, surely senses will prevail and it will be opt in

Comment: That's the plan. Also they probably won't deduplicate instances on the stack (see last section), so this would probably be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @SomeBody for pointing me in the right direction:

```cs
public static string ToUpperFirstLetter(string str)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        throw new ArgumentException(str);

    return string.Create(str.Length, str, (span, str) =>
    {
        str.AsSpan().CopyTo(span);
        span[0] = char.ToUpper(span[0]);
    });
}
```