# how to make 1st letter of each word capital using c# code

Tags: c#

//for e.g.

string s="this is example";

//how can i make output like "This Is Example"

using too simple code in c#??

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943273/convert-all-first-letter-to-upper-case-rest-lower-for-each-word

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're describing is sometimes called ProperCase, or in C# case, TitleCase.  It might seem like overkill, but as far as I know it takes some 'cultural' localization information.  Luckily you can just default to the one currently in use.

```
CultureInfo c   = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
TextInfo textInfo = c.TextInfo;

String newString = textInfo.ToTitleCase(oldString);
```

Of course in practice you'll probably want to put it all together like `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase`, but it can't hurt to see what all that crap means.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312890

Answer (score 10):

Try this.

```
String s = "this is example";
Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(s));
```

Comment: I would not use `ToLower`. `ToTitleCase` is sufficient.

Comment: +1, but with a note that in English (and other languages), making the first letter of every word uppercase is not "linguistically correct" as the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx) points out. So this method, even though it's called `ToTitleCase` doesn't actually capitalize the string according to the [title case rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Choice_of_case_in_text).

Comment: I think it should be `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture...`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code

```
Console.WriteLine(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(str));
```